# Обучение сети в игру "Морской бой"

Tags: нейронные-сети

Я полный ноль в машинном обучении, поэтому спрашиваю совет.
Пытаюсь обучить нейронную сеть играть в морской бой. Я только начальном этапе, поэтому жду, что сеть сообразит, что если ты попал в корабль больше чем одна палуба, то надо искать остальные палубы рядом.
Структура сети: 100 входов(поле 10х10), скрытый слой 100, один выход, который дает вероятность, для нужной ячейки(по очереди перебираю все ячейки и беру ту, у которой вероятность самая высокая)
Обучение:
Все выстрелы мимо это - 0
Всего палуб на всех кораблях у каждого игрока 20, поэтому я повышал веса при попадании каждую новую палубу (от 1/20 до 1) не помогло. Я ставил за отдельное попадание 0,5, попадание в последующую палубу 1. Тоже не помогло. В среднем ИИ закрывает поле за 65 ходов. Человек в в среднем за 50 ходов.
Подскажите куда копать

Comment: И всё-равно непонятно, какая у вас топология нейросети. Как-то всё очень умозрительно.